# strange `$Id` value added in linux source files

Tags: cvs, rcs

I've been working with linux-5.4.21 for some time and while updating the changed files to our local git repository I found some source files have some changes that I hadn't made. It's like this.
In drivers/edac/e7xxx_edac.c (compare the lines with `$Id`)
Before :

```
 *  Jim Garlick (Lawrence Livermore National Labs)
 *  Dave Peterson (Lawrence Livermore National Labs)
 *  That One Guy (Some other place)
 *  Wang Zhenyu (intel.com)
 *
 * $Id$
 *
 */

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>
```

After :

```
 *  Jim Garlick (Lawrence Livermore National Labs)
 *  Dave Peterson (Lawrence Livermore National Labs)
 *  That One Guy (Some other place)
 *  Wang Zhenyu (intel.com)
 *
 * $Id: edac_e7xxx.c,v 1.5.2.9 2005/10/05 00:43:44 dsp_llnl Exp $
 *
 */

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>
```

In drivers/net/plip/plip.c (compare the lines with `$Id`),

Before :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
/* $Id$ */
/* PLIP: A parallel port "network" driver for Linux. */
/* This driver is for parallel port with 5-bit cable (LapLink (R) cable). */
/*
 * Authors: Donald Becker <becker@scyld.com>
 *      Tommy Thorn <thorn@daimi.aau.dk>
```

After :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
/* $Id: plip.c,v 1.3.6.2 1997/04/16 15:07:56 phil Exp $ */
/* PLIP: A parallel port "network" driver for Linux. */
/* This driver is for parallel port with 5-bit cable (LapLink (R) cable). */
/*
 * Authors: Donald Becker <becker@scyld.com>
 *      Tommy Thorn <thorn@daimi.aau.dk>
```

I don't know how there automatically generated values were inserted to `$Id` in the source file. How are these generated and why? (I'm using arm64 toolchain)

Comment: That looks like keyword substitution from a previous source control system such as CVS. (The datestamp of 1997 on plip.c is too early for Subversion.)

Comment: Upstream kernel sources include the expanded keywords (from ancient times) but they have been collapsed in your "Before" sources for some reason. The upstream kernel git repos do not collapse any keywords. keyword substitution is not a native Git feature, and keyword expansion is seen as an undesirable feature by most Git users. So it must be something local.